# How to fix this issue with a rounded app bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I have an app bar in which I've applied a RoundedRectanlgeBorder to its shape property. The problem is when you scroll the view there is this extra white space in the corner of the app bar that is seen. The extra space that is 'clipped' off the app bar with the RoundedRectanlgeBorder is white instead of transparent. Is there a way to actually clip the app bar or some other workaround to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: You can use ThemeData.of(context).appBarTheme to customize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

`extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,`

in your scaffold

Comment: I just tried this but the issue remains unfortunately

Comment: Define your own ThemeData and set color to transparent then.

Comment: My apologies, I actually believe this answer solved the problem. Having SafeArea as a child of the Scaffold was preventing extendBodyBehindAppBar from actualizing.  thank you